# Enable Tracing Without Launch Configuration

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt

We have created a little control for development purposes to debug where we lose our handles. In it, we use the `DeviceData` to get the relevant information:

```
DeviceData info = Display.getDefault().getDeviceData();
System.out.println(info.tracking);
// now do something with info
```

However, to make that work, we have to open the launch configuration in Eclipse, go to the "Tracing" tab, and enable "debug" and "trace/graphics" for "org.eclipse.ui".

How would we enable this for the finished product? Is there a program argument? A parameter in some INI file? Could we enable this programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-debug <options file>` command line argument to specify the location of an options file containing the tracing to enable. Setting the `osgi.debug` environment variable is an alternative way of setting this.

The options file looks like:

```
org.eclipse.ui/debug=true
org.eclipse.ui/trace/graphics=true
```

Note: Most Eclipse plugins contain a file called `.options` which lists all the available debug options for the plugin. You can just copy that file somewhere and enable the options you want.